# What is wrong with my for loop

Tags: jquery, html, css, for-loop

I have a Jquery for loop that is activated when I click an element with the same class apart from itself though it doesn't do anything.

Here is the loop:

```
$('.container').click(function(){
    for(i = 1; i != 20; i++) {
        $('.container' + i + ' h1 a').click(function(){
            $('.container:not(.container' + i +')').hide();
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class='container container1'>
    <div class='content'>
        <h1><a href='#'>Title</a></h1>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='container container2'>
    <div class='content'>
                <h1><a href='#'>Title</a></h1>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='container container3'>
    <div class='content'>
                <h1><a href='#'>Title</a></h1>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have looked around and have found that the problem is that you can't run a function inside a for loop.

I know that I could do it with exstensive code but I think as more containers will be added that it would be easier to do it this way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: classic for loop scope issue. by the time any of the containers are clicked, i will be 20. Why are you binding click events in a click event?

Comment: How would I do it then

Comment: you'll need to give each iteration it's own scope either by using an IIFE or jQuery.each

Comment: See [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), though I don't think that's the only issue. If you show your HTML and *explain* what you are trying to achieve with the code, we will be able to help you find a better solution.

Comment: Providing the HTML code could help us. If container+i is an id, you need to put a #, not a dot.

Comment: container is not an id

Comment: @user2568107 What are you trying to do? Do you have individual classes like `.container1` and so on?

Comment: The part '.container' + i + 'h1 a' will give you something like '.container1h1 a', '.container2h1 a', etc.

Comment: so you have something class="container container1" , class="container container2" ?

Comment: Yes I have that in my HTML update

Comment: @user2568107 Your jQuery selector will be wrong. You will end up with `.container1h1 a` and so on. You need a space.

Comment: At least this '.container' + i + 'h1 a' need to be '.container' + i + ' h1 a' (with a space before the h1)

Comment: Have added that but still says the same error

Comment: I don't understand the code. Why do you bind a click event handler inside a click event handler? That doesn't seem to be correct. Do you simply want to hide all other containers if you click one?

Comment: I want to hide them all other than the one that was clicked

Comment: @user2568107 Please describe the error that you're seeing.

Comment: The error is in the description: can't run a function inside a for loop

Comment: @user2568107 That's what the console says? Or is that what you *think* is happening?

Comment: I tried it in jsfiddle ran check code and thats what it said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this way too complicated.

If you want to hide all other containers when you click one, you could just do this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.container').click(function () {
        $('.container').not(this).hide();
   });
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HCV8U/) with a working example...

If you want to make it so the `<p>` tags must get clicked, you can do it like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('p').click(function () {
        $('.container').not($(this).parents()).hide();
    });
});
```

Another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HCV8U/2/)

Comment: I would use this solution instead of mine if you're trying to allow for hiding of the divs when the entire div is clicked. My solution is valid when you want only the title link to hide the divs and not the other content in the div.

Comment: I could change about 8 characters and have mine do the same thing...  Just change the first selector.

Comment: so change the first selector to specify the anchor tag, hide all divs, then show the parent div.container of the anchor?

Answer (score 5):

> I want to hide them all other than the one that was clicked

I believe what you want is something like this:

```
var $container = $('.container').click(function(){
    $container.not(this).hide();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YZmqm/1/)

This will hide all other containers if a container is clicked. [Have a look at the jQuery API documentation to learn more about `.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

---

There are a couple of issues with your existing code:

- You are creating a function inside a loop. Due to how closures are implemented in JavaScript, this can lead to unexpected behavior if you are trying to access loo variables inside the function (which you do). Please see [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)
- You are binding new click event handler to all other `.container` elements whenever you click any of them of them. I.e. after you clicked three elements, every container will have 3 additional event handlers attached to it and each of them does the same.

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution and actually solves the OP's problem. Deleting mine.

Comment: I meant that when you click ed the link the function was run

Comment: Anyway that hides the p tags not the container

Comment: @user2568107: I assumed you wanted some kind of accordion (since you didn't explain much about what you are trying to do). If you want to hide the other containers completely, how are you going to show them again? If you want to do that, just remove the `.find('.content > p')` part.

Comment: I am going to have another button at the top that shows them and I know how to do that

Comment: @user2568107: Well ok then, updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to pass the reference to i as a parameter to the inner function such that the i is now local to the function. It appears that you're binding multiple events based on a click to the outer divs which is then binding multiple click events to the div's inner anchor tag to hide all divs which aren't a parent of the anchor tag.

Here is my solution:

HTML

```
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div class='container container1'>
        <div class='content'>
            <h1><a href='#'>Title</a></h1>
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='container container2'>
        <div class='content'>
            <h1><a href='#'>Title</a></h1>
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='container container3'>
        <div class='content'>
            <h1><a href='#'>Title</a></h1>
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var $context = $('#wrapper'),
    $containers = $('#wrapper').find('div.container');

$context.on('click', '.container a', function() {
    var $theAnchorClicked = $(this),
        parentClassofAnchor = $this.parent().parent().parent().prop('class'); 

   $containers.each(function() {
       $theCurrentContainer = $(this);
       if (!$(this).hasClass(parentClass)) $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

First, I wrapped the all 'container' divs in a wrapper div ('#wrapper') which is used as a context for finding the containers. This is simply because finding an element by an id, tag, or within a context is much faster than finding by class name. Always.

I saved a reference to the wrapper ($context) and then from $context found all the divs with the class 'container' and also saved a reference to that.

Second, instead of binding a click function to each link, I'm delegating a click event to the $context when a link inside the context is clicked (1 event bound instead of 20). I'm also using jQuery's .on() method as it is recommended for jQuery 1.7+.

So what's going on in the click event being delegated to $context? The .on() method is specifying a 'click' event on an element matching '.container a' and then the function to perform. In the function, this is a reference to the link being clicked.

The link being clicked is saved, as well as the class(es) of the parent div.container, e.g. '.container .container1'. You'll notice there are several parents being traversed to find it since the link is nested in several other elements.

Now that these are saved, I'm using jQuery's .each() method to traverse through all the containers we saved in $containers. We need to check for all the containers that don't have the class we found (parentClassofAnchor) and hide those. In the .each() function, this is not a reference to the link, it is now a reference to the current div.container in the loop ($theCurrentContianer). Then we use a simple if statement to check if it doesn't have the class we want to show, in which case we hide that div.

I hope this helps! Please let me know if you were looking to do more with your click events.